# Project is not working on IPhone where as it's working fine on Simulater

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am working on xamarin IOS and my project is working fine on IOS simulator but when i run on IPhone 6.  it's giving some issue.

"No valid iOS code signing keys found in keychain. You need to request a codesigning certificate from https://developer.apple.com.  RSystemApp.iOS"

Please tell me what will i do to solve this issue. if anyone have any idea to solve this issue or have any link to solve the issue please suggest me so that i can run my app on Iphone also

thanks

Comment: You will need to do device provisioning for your IPhone 6. If already done then download the profiles on your mac. Create a simple hello world application in xcode and run it on your device. The certificates will be downloaded on the phone. Then try to run your xamarin project.

Comment: ok I try and let you know if it will work

Answer (score 1):

When we have to run the iOS app on a device, we have to code sign the build. For that a valid provisioning profile and certificate is required.

1. Provisioning profile and developer certificate should be there on developer.apple.com, If not ten you have to create those there. Download those from there. Make sure you have added the device UDID while creating the provisioning profile.
2. Install provisioning and cert in your iPhone configuration utility and key chain.
3. Your bundle identifier should match with your AppID. You can confirm this by checking the provisioning profile in iPhone Configuration utility.
4. In Build Setting of your project, select these provisioning and certificate in code signing section.

If everything will be in this way, Your app will run on Device.

Comment: Sorry, I saw that your answer was essentially the same as mine. Too late at night. Though I added that it's a good idea to do a small test with XCode first to verify all is installed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Login to your Apple developer account and verify that you have everything in place to deploy an app on to an actual device:

- Do you have your certificates created and installed?
- Did you create your App ID?
- Have you registered your device(s)?
- Do you have a Provisioning Profile?

Are all these marked as correct on your build Mac? Best way is to check that with XCode before doing it with Xamarin Studio or Visual Studio.

Create a little test app in XCode if necessary and deploy it to your app.

Is that works, import the profile and certs into Xamarin/Visual Studio and it should work.